# Call method from subclass in superclass constructor - riddle

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I want to call `subclass` method in `superclass` but I don't know how.

I don't want to do something like this:

```
class A

  def initialize
    run
  end

  def run
    p "RUN"
    @runned = true
    method_from_b
  end

end

class B < A

  def method_from_b
    p @runned
  end

end

b = B.new
```

but more tricky

```
class A

  def self.create
    B.new # here I want to create a instance
  end

  create # call create

  def initialize
    run
  end

  def run
    p "RUN"
    @runned = true
    method_from_b
  end

end

class B < A

  def method_from_b
    p @runned
  end

end
```

I know what is wrong within, but how can I achieve this functionality?
I want to have method in `superclass` that will always call method from subclass but without explicit instance creation (by new).
If its impossible, so .. how `Test::Unit::TestCase` works?
To run test I could write `cmd: ruby test.rb` and the TestCase gets all methods stars with `test_` from testing class.
This is exactly what I need.

EDIT:

I think I've got it:

## file1.rb

```
require_relative 'file2'

class B
  def initialize
    p "A#initialize"
  end

  def method_from_b
    p @runned
  end
end
```

## file2.rb

```
module M

  def run
    p "RUN"
    @runned = true
    method_from_b
  end
end


class A

  def self.create
    p "create"
    require $0
    B.send(:include, M)
    a = B.new
    a.run
  end

  create

end
```

it works

Comment: Are you sure that `TestCase` doesn't create an instance?

Comment: I think that it creates but somewhere in the code (automatically) wait plz perhaps I've got an answer I will put in into edit

Comment: Parent class should have no knowledge about sub class, not to say calling sub classes' methods. That's one of the basics of object oriented programming.

Comment: @BillyChan of course, but I wanted to achieve something else

Comment: @reizals Instead of abstract things, or the solution itself, you can post real problems. I'm sure there must be one, if not lots of of nice OOP way to solve it.